# Handling passing variable with template string where value is out of scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function in my Node app, that makes use of the `mssql` package, to run some SQL updates. What I want to be able to do is pass in a variable for the actual update query/value, so that I can re-use the function. But I'm running into a problem where the value I'm passing in is `undefined` because of the scope.

To be clear, it will work if I do this:

```
  if (recordsToUpdate.length > 0 && sourceRecords.length > 0) {
    for (let record of recordsToUpdate) {
      for (let source of sourceRecords) {
        if (record.NoteDetailsId === source.notes_detail_id) {
          console.log('source.category: ', source.category);
          const updateQuery = `
            UPDATE Emp_Worksheets
            SET Category = '${source.category}';
          `;
          await sqlServerQueryHandler(updateQuery);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But if I move the `updateQuery` outside the function I get a 'source' is not defined error:

```
  let updateQuery = `
    UPDATE Emp_Worksheets
    SET Category = '${source.category}';
  `;

  if (recordsToUpdate.length > 0 && sourceRecords.length > 0) {
    for (let record of recordsToUpdate) {
      for (let source of sourceRecords) {
        if (record.NoteDetailsId === source.notes_detail_id) {
          console.log('source.category: ', source.category);
          await sqlServerQueryHandler(updateQuery);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I get around this? The error is on this line:

```
SET Category = '${source.category}';
```

Is there a way I can pass a default value instead? Obviously, `source` is available when the function runs, but I'm getting the error because `source` within the original declared variable doesn't yet exist. Perhaps there's an obvious way of handling this, but it is escaping me.

Comment: Well, it's not a constant, as its value depends on the `source`. Keep it in the scope where that variable is available, or put it in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic function and pass 3 parameters:

```
const updateQuery = (table, column, value) =>{
  return `UPDATE ${table} SET ${column} = ${value}`;
}
```

In order to avoid sql-injection you need to use Parameterized query:

One syntax for example:

`UPDATE ${table} SET ${column} = ?, [${value}]`

You can find more info about it [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query)

Comment: Returning a function is a good idea. But this `return UPDATE ${table} SET ${column} = ?, [${value}]` produces a syntax error. Also, this is an in-house tech team app. No public access, behind a firewall.

Comment: Hi, incase you succeeded with the 1st example, you need to check the right syntax for the parametriez query according to your db engine. You can specify what db you are using and I will help you with that too.

Comment: I am writing to a SQL Server database.

Comment: So I guess that you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: That's correct, yes. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Great. So it syntax for parameters is: ...
            .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
            .query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter') ...